# Old version of Foundation seems to be installing rather than Foundation 5

Tags: installation, sass, version, zurb-foundation

I am trying out Ruby, scss, and Foundation for the first time. When I try and do `gem install foundation` in the ruby command it installs foundation 1.0.4 and I'm not sure why. I'm presuming that's an old version. I did manage to get foundation 4 and scss installed but I'd prefer to use the new Foundation 5.

Sidenote: The default Foundation 4 site worked but the one I set up with Foundation '5' was only text. I am presuming it is because the wrong version of foundation was installed and I don't see any way to specify.

I followed the instructions including the Windows only part about git, and using up to date version of ruby (1.9 I believe) and I installed a ton of stuff and I'm presuming I installed it all as I was able to install foundation I just don't know why it's such an old version.

Thank you for any help.

P.S. I don't know if I should give up and use the normal css installer and then make my own scss separately and convert it and put it in the foundation site instead of all this. I've not used scss before so I'm not sure of the advantages of installing the sass version rather than the css version as I think you convert your scss into css when adding it to your directory anyway? but perhaps not. Or perhaps it's so I can edit the scss files of Foundation 5 itself rather than only my own scss/css files?

Answer (score 1):

When you run `gem install foundation` (version 1.0.4), you are installing the Zurb Foundation command line tool, not the Foundation framework

Zurb foundation uses bower to manage the updating of Foundation. See the [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html) for more details.
But you need Node installed as well to have it work, so you would run

```
npm install -g bower grunt-cli
```

(which installs the node packages bower and grunt on your machine ) then run

```
gem install foundation
```

and finally you're ready to create a new app with

```
foundation new YOUR_APP
```

and you're good to go.

Only if you're trying to use Foundation 5 with a Ruby on Rails project, you can use the `foundation-rails` gem by adding `gem 'foundation-rails'` to your `Gemfile` and running `bundle` (see the [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/applications.html) for more details)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification about version numbers. That makes sense. :) It seems like I have done everything you said already. My problem is that the default website it creates is just text, I don't think the css is working, whereas if I create a new project with foundation 4 I get a working default foundation webpage. Surely if I've yet to change anything the new project/website should be functional? There is a Bower folder etc and I didn't get any errors. Thanks.

Comment: For example, on the index page to both foundation4 and 5 default projects, the stylesheet link is:   <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/app.css"> which doesn't exist in the foundation 5 default project, just foundation 4, so are some files not being created or have I gotten confused?

Comment: It works when I copy in the stylesheets folder from the default foundation 4 created profile but I'm worried this will cause issues since it's presumably and outdated version and since it clearly should have been there to begin with.

Comment: I just followed those instructions again and did `foundation new testapp` and when I went to `testapp/bower_components/foundation/bower.json`, it said it was using  foundation version 5.0.2, what does it say on yours?

Comment: Just follow the instruction. After that go to your project directory and create file stylesheets/app.css . then in your teminal go to your project directory and run : compass watch .
It should update the app.css file. good luck mate.

Comment: Wow I'm so sorry that I didn't reply to this. At some point I lost my stackoverflow login and began using a different account. I did what you said and it says:
"
{
  "name": "foundation",
  "version": "5.0.2",
  "main": ["css/foundation.css", "js/foundation.js"],
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery" : ">= 2.0.0",
    "modernizr": ">= 2.6.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
"

So I guess I was using the most up to date version of Foundation all along, I was just thrown because it didn't say on the default page like Foundation 4 had, and I didn't know how to check until you said. Thank you. :)